# How to use sickit learn to calculate the k-means feature importance

Tags: scikit-learn, k-means

I use scikit-learn to do clustering by k-means:

```
from sklearn import cluster 
k = 4
kmeans = cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=k)
```

but another question is :
How to use scikit learn to calculate the k-means feature importance？

Comment: Can you describe what `feature importance` in the setting of clustering means?

Comment: Since the answer to this question requires some explanation of stats concepts, it may be more appropriate for [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, to my knowledge  there is no such thing as "feature importance" in the context of a k-means algorithm - at least in the understanding that feature importance means "automatic relevance determination" (as in the link below).

In fact, the k-means algorithm treats all features equally, since the clustering procedure depends on the (**unweighted**) Euclidean distances between data points and cluster centers.

More generally, there exist clustering algorithms which perform automatic feature selection or automatic relevance determination, or generic feature selection methods for clustering. A specific (and arbitrary) example is 
 [Roth and Lange, Feature Selection in Clustering Problems](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/2486-feature-selection-in-clustering-problems.pdf), NIPS 2003

Answer (score 1):

I have answered this on StackExchange, you can partially estimate the most important features for, not the whole clustering problem, rather each cluster's most important features. Here is the answer:

> I faced this problem before and developed two possible methods to find the most important features responsible for each K-Means cluster sub-optimal solution.
>
> 1. Focusing on each centroid’s position and the dimensions responsible for the highest Within-Cluster Sum of Squares minimization
> 2. Converting the problem into classification settings (Inspired by the paper: "A Supervised Methodology to Measure the Variables Contribution to a Clustering").
>
> I have written a detailed article here [Interpretable K-Means: Clusters Feature Importances](https://towardsdatascience.com/interpretable-k-means-clusters-feature-importances-7e516eeb8d3c). GitHub link is included as well if you want to try it.